# Grails, different url for same controller and action

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I have this urlMappings in grails

`"/"(controller: 'home', action: 'index')
"/$id"(controller: 'home', action: 'index')`

is there a better way to write this, without duplicate code?
If I use only one, the other urlMapping won't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In this case wouldn't making `$id` optional be the same as combining the two?: `"/$id?"(controller: 'home, action: 'index')`

Comment: Nop, for some reason it returns a not found.
HTTP Status 404 - "/index.gsp" not found.

Comment: Elaborate on how this url mappings are invoked. Mentioning "for some reason" will not help. @JoshuaMoore 's suggestion is the proposed approach to handle these kind of scenarios.

Comment: I just tried this on my own app, and @JoshuaMoore's initial suggestion is 100% accurate. If it isn't working for you, it is a different problem.

Comment: Is working now, i think I was doing something wrong before. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to combine the two URL mappings you can do so by making the `id` parameter optional like this:

`"/$id?"(controller: 'home', action: 'index')`

Comment: It worked using this:
"/**"(controller: 'home', action: 'index')

Comment: But that pattern means it will match EVERYTHING that wasn't already matched previously.